# Resolution of Rational Singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, singularity

Let $X$ be a normal scheme. Let $s$ be a singular point and (for sake of simplicity) $X \backslash s$ regular. One says that $s$ is a ***rational singularity*** (generally: X has rational singularities if there are more then one such $s$)  if $X$  is normal, of finite type over a field of characteristic zero, and there exists a proper birational map

$f: Y \to X$

from a regular scheme $Y$  such that the higher direct images of $f_{*}$ applied to $O_Y$  are trivial. That is,

$$ R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}=0$$

for $i>0$.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_singularity or Artin paper mentioned on the linked page.

$f$ is also called resolution of singularities (of $X$) and has the property that the restriction $$f \vert _{Y \backslash f^{-1}(s)}: Y \backslash f^{-1}(s) \to X \backslash s$$ is an isomorphism.

This definition has one problem:

Does it say that there exist ***one*** such (special) resolution $f$ with $ R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}=0$ (that would be a stupid definition) or does the property

(*)$$ R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}=0$$

hold for ***every*** resolution of $X$. The statement says nothing about the uniqueness of such resolutions of singularities.

So my question is how to verify that the condition (*) is ***independent*** of choosen resolution $f: Y \to X$ of the singularity.

In other words: If one resolution has property (*), then all.

Comment: This is not a problem. For any two resolutions of singularities, there is a third dominating them both, and it is straightforwards to show that you can take the vanishing of the higher direct image from one to the dominating resolution back to the other resolution that it dominates. (You'll want to look up Hironaka's theorem to understand what dominating means, but otherwise it's pretty direct.)

Comment: @KReiser: I still not sure about your argument how to use the "dominating resolution" to deduce that $R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}=0$ is independent or the choice of the resolution. Assume we have two resolutions $f: Y \to X, h: Z \to X$ with $R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}=0$ and we want to prove that the same holds for higher images of $h$. If we use the dominating argument we find a dominating resolution $W$ with morphisms $\bar{f}: W \to Y$ and $\bar{h}: W \to Z$ such that $\bar{f} \circ f= \bar{h} \circ h: W \to X$ a resolution.

Comment: @KReiser: Do you mean this? If yes, then let continue:

Then using Leray Serre sequence we conclude by 

$$0=R^ p\bar{f}_* R^ qf_* \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow R^{p + q}(\bar{f} \circ f)_*\mathcal{F}$$

Therefore $R^{p + q}(\bar{f} \circ f)_*\mathcal{F}=R^{p + q}(\bar{h} \circ h)_*\mathcal{F}=0$. But how we can from here "go back" to conclude $R^{i}h_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Z}=0$?

Comment: If the RHS of the spectral sequence is zero, then apply the backward argument with $p >0$ and $q = 0$. One needs that for $f: W \to Z$, $f_* O_W = O_Z$. (Sorry, I lost track of the index of maps.)

Comment: ...and this is no problem since the resolutions are compositions of blowing ups of ***points***, so $\bar{h}_* O_W = O_Z$ holds in our case

Comment: I am not sure if resolutions are compositions of blowing ups of points, but the result holds without such an assumption.

Comment: @Youngsu: hmm so if we assume that $\bar{h}_* O_W = O_Z$ holds how do you proceed in case $p>0,q=0$? Then again Leray tells 
$$\bar{h}_* R^ ph_* \mathcal{F}= R^ 0\bar{h}_* R^ ph_* \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow R^{p}(\bar{h} \circ h)_*\mathcal{F}=0$$

Why are we here done? Or did I misunderstood your hint?

Comment: I thought a bit about the problem and reduced it to the following:

Assume $f:Y \to X$ is a resolution of the singularity and $p: W \to Y$ the "dominating resolution" (exists, as KReiser remarked). So if we denote $g= p \circ f:W \to X$ then if suffice to show that 

$$R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}= R^{i}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}$$

holds. Then we are done, right?

Now again Leray Serre says

$$R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}(R^{j}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}) \Rightarrow R^{i+j}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}$$

Comment: If we could show that $R^{j}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}=0$ for $j>0$ then $R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}= R^{i}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}$ since other terms collapse. So the problem is, why $R^{j}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}=0$ if we know that $Y$ is regular?

Comment: By the way: Does the generalization

$$R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {F}}= R^{i}p_{*}{f^*\mathcal  {F}}$$

hold for general quasicoherent $\mathcal  {F}$ under same conditions on $p,f$ and $g$ as above?

Comment: Sorry, but you have put too many comments in different directions. I could not follow everything. This is regarding the comment right below mine. You put the indices wrong. The first component has the exponent p and the next one needs to be 0.

Comment: Yes, sorry in my last three comments I changed the strategy of my proof so some notations from former and new attempt overlapped. So essentially forget all older notations from former comments and consider ***only*** the setting from my last three comments. So from "I thought a bit blabla ...".

Comment: Essentially we have following problem: Why $R^{j}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}=0$ under assumption that $Y$ is non singular.

Comment: Remark: In the comment above there is a typo: I mean of course $R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}= R^{i}g_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}$ insted of $R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}= R^{i}p_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{W}$

Comment: see https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~coskun/HKU%20Singularities2012.pdf