# Higher Direct Images of Birational Morphisms between Regular Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, blowup

Let $X$ be a ***normal, of finite type over a field of characteristic zero and regular*** scheme. Let $s \in X$ be a closed point. Assume we have a proper birational map

$f: Y \to X$

with the property that the restriction $$f \vert _{Y \backslash f^{-1}(s)}: Y \backslash f^{-1}(s) \to X \backslash s$$ is an isomorphism.

My question is how to deduce that  the higher direct images of $f_{*}$ applied to $O_Y$  vanish for $i>0$. That is,

$$ R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y}=0$$

for $i>0$.

Obviously this is true on the restruction $X \backslash s$. But what about $ R^{i}f_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Y} \vert _U$ for an open neighbourhood of $s$?

Does anybody see an argument?

Remark: Background of this problem is following former thread of mine: [Resolution of Rational Singularities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3303877/resolution-of-rational-singularities)

where I tried to deduce that the property of a ***rational singularity*** at a isolated singular point $s$  of a normal scheme $W$ for proper birational map (=the resolution of the singularity)

$h: Z \to W$

from a regular scheme $Z$  that the higher direct images vanish, so

(*) $$ R^{i}h_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Z}=0$$

for $i>0$ is ***independent*** of the choice of the resolution.

Namely, if I choose another resolution of the singularity $h': Z' \to W$ then (*) holds also for $h'$.

With help of KReiser and Youngsu the problem could be reduced to following problem (via "dominating argument"... see comments in the linked thread):

Assume $h:Z \to W$ has a dominating resolution $g: D \to Z$ with $k:= h \circ g, D \to W$ and by a symmetry argument it suffice to show that

$$R^{i}h_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{Z}= R^{i}k_{*}{\mathcal  {O}}_{D}$$

Using Leray Serre spectral sequence the problem reduces to show that

$$R^jg_*{\mathcal  {O}}_{D}=0$$

for $j >0$ (see again the linked thread).

Since $Z$ is ***regular*** we are now in the above setting for $f:Y \to X$.

Comment: Did you google? The _first result_ is a [paper on the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.1827.pdf) with a proof of the theorem plus reference (on the first page!) to the original result of Hironaka in the characteristic zero case complete with page number.